# Correct MIME type for data URL

Tags: mime-types, data-uri

I have an image which is encoded as a Data URL ([RFC 2397](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397), formerly "data URI", commonly used in browsers), so it looks like `"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQA..."`.  It has its own media type and encoding specified internally, but is itself an ascii-compatible string.  What's the right content type to use to describe data in this already-wrapped format?

I know I could unwrap it from the data-url format and use the underlying content-type (in this case `image/jpeg`), but for reasons out-of-scope of this question, that's complicated in my scenario.  Plus, this format should have its own content type, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there might not be a correct answer to this question yet, and this SO question might itself define a reasonable answer for others asking this question, I'll document here my own proposal that I'm using:

```
application/dataurl
```

This is inspired by [the accepted MIME-type for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type), which is `application/json`.  This seems appropriate to me as both are data formats which can wrap arbitrary content.

Comment: MIME types are standardized. If you want to propose a new MIME type, you’d need to go through IANA, not Stack Overflow. In the meantime, you can always define your own ad hoc type as an extension, e.g., text/x-data-url.